# Convert zip file timestamps to human readable format

Tags: zip, timestamp, hex

How can the file last modification date and time, for files in a zip file, be converted to a human readable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it!

The zip file timestamp in the same format as the FAT timestamp. You can find out how to convert it at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#Directory_table)

Or at other stackoverflow question:
[Unix timestamp to FAT timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763259/unix-timestamp-to-fat-timestamp)